# Inlustrus: A conundrum

Tags: word-request

I stumbled upon this exchange so I hope you can help me. I'm writing a book of poetry, and I wanted to title it Starlight, but why use English, am I right? So I made the rookie error with Google translate and got inlustris, which I love only to find out it doesn't mean start light, but it still works on multiple levels. I'm just not sure which declination to use. Help?

Answer (score 4):

The adjective "inlustris" is 3rd Declension.  So for the title of a book of poems, you'd probably want a neuter plural nominative form, "Inlustria", as in "Carmina Inlustria" = "Illustrious Poems"

Note that you could also use the alternative spelling "ill-" instead of "inl-".

See [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=inlustris&la=la#lexicon) for more details